# Compiling using arm-none-eabi-gcc and linking library liba.a error

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm, processor

I am compiling a hello world program in C on a 64-bit Linux machine. I am using a GCC ARM embedded toolchain to cross compile my program on a FOX G20 V board with an ATMEL AT91SAM9G20 processor.

On the first take, I had a few errors when compiling because the program didn't recognize the printf, return etc. functions (the standard C functions). So I decided to make the link between the functions, which I believe are defined in the libc.a library (correct me if I'm wrong), by doing `arm-none-eabi-gcc -o hello hello.c libc.a` but the outcome still results in errors:

```
libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x16): undefined reference to `_exit'
libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): In function `_write_r':
writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x10): undefined reference to `_write'
libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): In function `_close_r':
closer.c:(.text._close_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_close'
libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function `_fstat_r':
fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0xe): undefined reference to `_fstat'
libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function `_isatty_r':
isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_isatty'
libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): In function `_lseek_r':
lseekr.c:(.text._lseek_r+0x10): undefined reference to `_lseek'
libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): In function `_read_r':
readr.c:(.text._read_r+0x10): undefined reference to `_read'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm really unsure as to why the program still does not recognize the standard functions even though I've linked the library to the application. If anyone has a reason as to why, or a solution as to how I can fix this problem, I would be very grateful.

**UPDATE**

I've downloaded the glibc library from [here](http://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/gnu/libc/). I've compiled and created a static library from the `syscalls.c` library that I found in `newlib-2.1.0/libgloss/arm` and when I link the library to my application code, I still get the same error.

Comment: Exactly what GCC ARM embedded toolchain are you using?  It looks like the undefined references are functions that you are (or someone is) expected to write to integrate the `libc.a` library to the specific platform.

Comment: @MichaelBurr It's the pre-built 32-bit version of Linero GCC. So there is something that I would have to add to the `libc.a` library? What could that be if so?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try executing this:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --specs=rdimon.specs -lgcc -lc -lm -lrdimon -o hello hello.c
```

Your toolkit seems to provide the librdimon.a, a library which provides the basic standard C functions.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error because my binary cannot fit the ROM.

My first error was:

```
address 0x34000 of arm_flash.elf section `.mmu_tbl' is not within region `ps7_ram_0`
```

Then I've got the same list of undefined reference errors.

I need to reduce the binary size, by removing `new` keywords, and all dynamic memory allocation from my C++ code.