# Contiki port will not override printf

Tags: c, gcc, arm, printf, contiki

I am trying to create a port of contiki for my custom platform using an stm32l1 processor. However when i am trying to override the default printf function from `arm-none-eabi-gcc` newlib it will not let me.

I have tried creating hedaer and source files, adding them to be built and then either creating the function 'printf' and 'sprintf' in them or naming them something different and then trying to use 
`#define printf my_printf`.

I have also followed other tips i found online that tells me to create a newlib stub file providing the various functions `_sbrk , _write , _read...` and so on.

However everytime i try to build my program with any printf command, the linker complains on all the newlib stub files with undefinded references.

`undefined reference to _sbrk`

How can i get the contiki build system to override the standard printf function?

On ubuntu14:10 with gcc 4.93.

`CC        targets/r1501/printf/printf-stdarg.c
  CC        contiki/../arm/stm32l152/./syscalls.c
  CC        .... 
  CC        contiki/core/net/mac/cxmac/cxmac.c
  AR        contiki-r1501.a
  CC        project.c
  LD        project.r1501
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/libg.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function`_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/libg.a(lib_a-writer.o): In function`_write_r':
writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x10): undefined reference to `_write'
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/libg.a(lib_a-closer.o): In function`_close_r':

....More errors from libg.a `

In the syscalls.c file all of theese undefined references are specified.
and printf and sprintf are defined in printf-sdarg.c

> arm-none-eabi-gcc -DCONTIKI=1 -DCONTIKI_TARGET_R1501=1
>   -DNETSTACK_CONF_WITH_IPV6=1 -DUIP_CONF_IPV6_RPL=1 -DAUTOSTART_ENABLE -DHSE_VALUE=8000000 -DF_CPU=32000000 -DPLL_SOURCE_HSE -D'GIT_DESC="v0.1-23-g0c3a4d8-dirty"' -specs=nosys.specs -I. -Icontiki/core -Icontiki/../arm/stm32l152 -Icontiki/../arm/stm32l152/loader -Icontiki/../arm/stm32l152/lib/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc -Icontiki/../arm/stm32l152/lib/CMSIS/Include -Icontiki/../arm/stm32l152  -Icontiki/platform/r1501  -DWITH_ASCII -DMCK=32000000 -mlittle-endian -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -msoft-float -Wno-strict-aliasing  -DRUN_AS_SYSTEM -DROM_RUN -std=c99 -g -lc -larchive -Lcontiki/../arm/stm32l152 -fdiagnostics-color=always  -O0  -I. -Itargets/r1501/. -Itargets/r1501/dev -Itargets/r1501/rf230bb -Itargets/r1501/printf -Icontiki/../arm/stm32l152/. -Icontiki/../arm/stm32l152/lib/STM32L1xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src -Icontiki/core/dev -Icontiki/core/lib -Icontiki/core/net -Icontiki/core/net/llsec -Icontiki/core/net/mac -Icontiki/core/net/rime -Icontiki/core/net/rpl -Icontiki/core/sys -Icontiki/core/cfs -Icontiki/core/ctk -Icontiki/core/lib/ctk -Icontiki/core/loader -Icontiki/core/. -Icontiki/apps/ping6 -Icontiki/core/sys -Icontiki/core/dev -Icontiki/core/lib -Icontiki/core/net/ipv6 -Icontiki/core/net/ip -Icontiki/core/net/rpl -Icontiki/core/net/mac -Icontiki/core/net/llsec -Icontiki/core/net/mac/sicslowmac -Icontiki/core/net/rime -Icontiki/core/net -Icontiki/core/net/mac/contikimac -Icontiki/core/net/mac/cxmac -Itargets/r1501/ -Icontiki -DCONTIKI_VERSION_STRING=\"Contiki-2.6-2077-ga79edc6\" -DAUTOSTART_ENABLE -c project.c -o project.co arm-none-eabi-gcc -L contiki/../arm/stm32l152 -T contiki/../arm/stm32l152/stm32l1xx.ld -g
>   -nostartfiles -mthumb  -fdiagnostics-color=always   project.co obj_r1501/contiki-main.o \
>       contiki-r1501.a  -o project.r1501 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/libg.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':

Comment: You need to at least post the linker's output. The define-solution should even work in very strange scenarios. Are you sure all your issues are printf related?

Comment: I added some output to the code, the "CC ..." is just a shortened down list of many many internal things in contiki being compiled, without errors or warnings

Comment: Grepping the contiki-r1501.a file for the undefined functions finds them in there.

Comment: Adding theese flags: --specs=rdimon.specs -lgcc -lc -lm -lrdimon as indicated by  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102500/compiling-using-arm-none-eabi-gcc-and-linking-library-liba-a-error to the linker will get me into the newlibs printf, this will take me to the edge of my memory though.

Comment: Curiously, *not* including `<stdio.h>` helped me to avoid such errors on an ARM-based STM board. Provide your own protototypes for `printf` and `putchar` instead of including the system header.

Comment: I did not solve this. However, disabling any usage of printf in the file rf230bb.c makes the problem go away. So i have located the error though.
However, since i am under time pressure this will have to do for now.