# Linker/loader errors (unresolved function name symbols) in openr.c and writer.c

Tags: arduino

Compiled Arduino source and, at end of the build, got the unresolved symbols (function entry point names) for `openr.c` and `writer.c`

The invocation arguments used were consistent with the `_open_r()` and `_write_r()` function definitions, and they compile without errors.

Any suggestions on why this error came up,  or even what openr.c and writer.c do are welcomed.

> <sup>/home/digysol/arduino-1.8.0/hardware/tools/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7e-m/fpu/libc.a(lib_a-openr.o):   In function "_open_r": `openr.c:(.text._open_r+0x10)`:
>
>           undefined reference to "_open"</sup>
>
> <sup>/home/digysol/arduino-1.8.0/hardware/tools/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7e-m/fpu/libc.a(lib_a-writer.o):     In function "_write_r": `writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x10)`:
>
>            undefined reference to "_write"</sup>
>
> <sup>collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status</sup>

Comment: <del>Are you doing this on linux or windows..?</del> Stupid question never mind I see your file paths.

Comment: Arduino is not C. And see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

`undefined reference to "_open"` I look at this and it automatically tells me it's a missing library.

The `libc.a` binary looks like it's trying to use it. So maybe libc.a is having trouble building with missing params, see a [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102500/compiling-using-arm-none-eabi-gcc-and-linking-library-liba-a-error).